# Add divider to column css

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a row with 2 columns with a divider as shown below:

[image]

There is a light divider and also a white divider that should increase according to text amount like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in CSS so that the white line divider increases based on the text amount in either column?

Comment: Could you add your html and css please?

Comment: Use CSS `columns` for the parent with a custom `column-rule` instead of Flexbox. [w3schools: CSS column property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp). And make sure to post a [reprex] as questions without are bound to get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container for the long-stick border, and apply a short-stick border on text elements

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.text-container {
  padding: 1rem 0; /*Create a top-bottom padding for text container*/
  width: 50%;
}

.text-container span {
  padding: 0 1rem; /*Create a left-right padding for text*/
  display: block;
}

.text-container:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; /*Border on text container*/
}

.text-container:first-of-type span {
  border-right: 4px solid #ddd; /*Border on text*/
  margin-right: -2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="text-container">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body {
  background: #111;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  background: #222;
  color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.textcontainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  align-self: stretch;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-left: 0.5px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <p class="text">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
    </p>
    <span class="divider"></span>
    <p class="text">
      Hello World. this is a test. And it looks awesome to design.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Other respective answers do not address the problem that either column `A` or `B` can have variable content. And explicitly applying margin to any of the columns wouldn't solve the problem `white divider that should increase according to text amount like this` and `white line divider increases based on the text amount in either column`.

**Solution**

I couldn't think of any CSS solution as there is not any available way to get elements height through CSS. Have to use a tiny bit of JS to solve the problem.

```js
// get paragraphs height
let heightColA = document.querySelector('.col-a p').offsetHeight;
let heightColB = document.querySelector('.col-b p').offsetHeight;
// applying border after checking if either Col A or Col B has more height
if (heightColA > heightColB) {
  document.querySelector('.col-a p').style = 'border-right: 5px solid #fff; margin-right: -5px;'
} else {
  document.querySelector('.col-b p').style = 'border-left: 5px solid #fff; margin-left: -5px;'
}
// console.log(heightColA, heightColB)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container>div {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .col-a {
  border-right: 5px solid #d00;
}

.container>div>p {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-a">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, hic provident? Iste commodi neque corrupti debitis mollitia atque, eveniet iure!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, hic provident? Iste commodi neque corrupti debitis mollitia atque, eveniet iure! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Minima ipsum dolorem, nisi voluptates, rerum
      ipsa labore eius aliquam quas magni amet. Accusantium architecto perspiciatis, minus non voluptatibus totam sequi. Placeat sint error doloremque eveniet quibusdam quo delectus, laboriosam alias autem voluptatum unde eum, officiis omnis vel molestias
      dolorem distinctio nulla! Voluptatem qui explicabo corrupti autem consequuntur cupiditate sequi quos reprehenderit velit, porro, assumenda, officiis deserunt! Corrupti qui perspiciatis nemo. Repellendus qui facilis similique earum molestias distinctio
      quae sed, laboriosam laudantium corporis, suscipit, dolor accusamus pariatur iste nam. Exercitationem ab vitae eveniet. Blanditiis, facilis quidem eos ad aut quibusdam laudantium a!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try increasing content in any of the column, the white divider will increase accordingly.

Hope this answers the questions.